# How to restore code of pyfunc class in MlFlow?

Tags: python, mlflow

I have lost a code of my pyfunc class which I uploaded to MlFlow. Model is working on a production but via MLFlow UI I can't get code view of model class. For some R models I can get code class using load_model. After call this method I get the whole code view of class which is uploaded to MlFlow. Unfortunately, it doesnt work the same way in python. All files are inside hdfs directory of MLFlow.

```
import mlflow
logged_model = '"file:///var/mm/mlflow/artifacts/***/*******/artifacts/my_model_name'

# Load model as a PyFuncModel.
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)
```

After invoking to loaded_model I get only some not important infos about model:

```
mlflow.pyfunc.loaded_model:
  artifact_path: my_model_name
  flavor: mlflow.pyfunc.model
  run_id: *****
```

How can I check the code of the class which was uploaded to MLFlow earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible by default. You can associate code files with the model using the code_paths parameter of the log_model function

```
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(
    model,
    "model",
    code_paths=["./evaluate_on_regressor.py"]
)
```